# aws config file to connect to s3 client

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

This is the line of code I use to connect to my boto3 client.

```
s3_client = boto3.client('s3', aws_access_key_id = '<access-key>', aws_secret_access_key = '<secret-key>')
```

How can I modify it to adapt to config file credentials within ~/.aws/config. For example, if I have

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id = FOO
aws_secret_access_key = BAR

[recordings]
aws_access_key_id = ABC
aws_secret_access_key = DEF
```

How can I set my python code to use recordings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the easiest way to achieve what you want:

```
session = boto3.Session(profile_name='recordings')
s3_client = session.client('S3')
```

Best, Stefan